# How to pass another flag variable in addition to collections to a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**How can I pass a `is_featured = true` to the following partial?**

`<%= render :partial => 'stores', :collection => @stores %>`

I only need to pass the `is_featured` in one place (in all other places I call the partial as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `locals` option of render

```
<%= render :partial => 'stores', :collection => @stores, :locals => { :is_featured => is_featured } %>
```

In the partial you would access it as a method:

```
<%= is_featured %>
```

Comment: Since this is Rails 3, you should be able to shorten that to        `<%= render @stores, :is_featured => is_featured %>`